# LVM merge destroyed hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, lvm, snapshot

I tried to upgrade from Kubuntu 22.04 to 22.10, and borked it.
Accidentally pressed Ctrl-C with the terminal window active.
I think I was able to fix everything, but didn't want to chance it.

I had an LVM snapshot, so I tried to restore it from a live USB, and this seems to have destroyed the hard drive.
I am completely mystified.

To create the snapshot, I did the following (this is from memory):

```
sudo lvcreate --snaphot --name Kubutu-snap --size 20G /dev/vg1/Kubuntu
```

To restore the snapshot:

```
sudo lvconvert --merge /dev/vg1/Kubuntu-snap
```

After I saw "Merge 100%" and the command terminated, I restarted the computer.
Upon reboot, I got a message about my hard drive being missing.

Further info:

- I was a bit hasty pulling the flash drive from my computer after restarting. But I don't see how this could kill the internal drive.
- I don't know if the snapshot was overfull. I would have thought that there would be a warning if this were the case. I also can't see how this would hurt anything beside than the logical volume in question.
- The drive is a SATA SSD.
- I was connected to power the whole time.
- `sda` used to be my SSD. `sdb` is the live USB.

Debugging.
Upon rebooting to my live USB, it is unclear what is up with the SSD.
`df` gives nothing.

`lsblk` is unhelpful.

```
$ sudo lsblk
...
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
(loop devices)
sda      8:0    1     0B  0 disk
sdb      8:16   0  29.2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   3.4G  0 part /cdrom
├─sdb2   8:18   0   4.1M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0   300K  0 part 
└─sdb4   8:20   0  25.8G  0 part /var/crash
                                 /var/log
...
$ sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL
...
UUID                                 NAME   FSTYPE     SIZE MOUNTPOINT               LABEL                   MODEL
(loop devices)
                                     sda                 0B                                                  SD/MMC
2022-04-19-10-22-47-00               sdb    iso9660   29.2G                          Kubuntu 22.04 LTS amd64 Extreme
2022-04-19-10-22-47-00               ├─sdb1 iso9660    3.4G /cdrom                   Kubuntu 22.04 LTS amd64 
8D6C-A9F8                            ├─sdb2 vfat       4.1M                          ESP                     
                                     ├─sdb3            300K                                                  
783b59ea-3cd8-4ef9-95e1-0d7cc906e5e6 └─sdb4 ext4      25.8G /var/crash               writable 
...
```

`smartctl` is unhelpful.

```
$ sudo smartctl -d scsi -a /dev/sda
...
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               Generic-
Product:              SD/MMC
Revision:             1.00
Compliance:           SPC-4
Logical Unit id:      0x00e04c2020202000error: designator length
Serial number:        2012090114345300
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Fri Dec 23 23:39:16 2022 UTC
NO MEDIUM present in device
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

Clearly, "SD/MMC" is not correct.

So, the questions:

1. What on earth happened?
2. Can I fix this?

Comment: I believe `smartctl` is for HDDs, not SSDs.   
Also try `sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL`

Comment: I reran lsblk with those options. No change.

Comment: Ah, it did not mean to fix anything, it could just give you another perspective about how things look. But they don't look anyhow. I don't even know how to interpret that return value.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I mean no new information.

Comment: `sda` is a Secure Digital / MultiMedia Card device (`SD/MMC`). Is that supposed to be your live environment from which you booted? Anyhow, your SSD is not even visible at all...

Comment: Well, the SSD would have been `sda`, and there's no memory card in my computer. The only other device, `sdb`, is the live USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
After some investigation of generic SSD problems, I tried opening the computer and reseating the SSD.
The computer wouldn't turn on at all after that.
I pressed the reset switch, and everything booted fine.
Not sure which step did the trick.

So mystery solved: LVM merge *did not* in fact destroy my hard drive.
I'll have to keep troubleshooting if this happens again.